# Game development - Update method and State pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, game-engine

For my game, I use a State Pattern to handle my screens. The screen need to update and render each frame. And the game loop is in the Game class.

But I also need an update and render method in the Entity class. Should I use an interface in the Screen and Entity class (e.g. FrameProcess) ? Or can I leave it like this (see image)?

What is the best pratice in OOP ? Are there any pattern for that ?

Basic UML of this problem:

[image]

Comment: What would happen you if derived Entity from Screen and handed your Game object an Entity instead of a GameScreen or MenuScreen?

Comment: Yes there's a pattern for state machines, and I've even provided an abstract [framework](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/) for that.

Comment: @DanielT. I want to have different screen in my game. A title screen, a menu screen and a game screen. And in my GameScreen I would have my game with level that contains entities that are the player, enemy, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create pure virtual functions for `update()` and `render()` methods in the `Entity` class and let the classes that inherit from it define their own behaviour which will let the system behave in a polymorphic manner. Then in `Game` class or some other type of handler class call `update()` and `draw()` methods based on the current state of the system which decides it using the State pattern.

Btw, it tells more about State pattern and its example usage(s) in a very clear manner at http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "Entity" in this context. If an entity covers everything that is renderable AND updatable, creating a virtual function for both would be fine (If you plan on deriving other types of Entity like vehicles or weapons). If you have other renderable and updatable types other than Entity, an interface would be the better option in my opinion.

You might also be better off checking out https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for further Q&A on gamedev.